# VB.NET Grid View with exapnding textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Inside a grid view with (4 databound fields),if one row is clicked,that row must be expanded **down** with 14 **databound** text fields(not same line) and button.

I have tried by placing a hyperlink in gridview ,while clicking that,aonother form will open with the 14 textboxes for updaton.But i don't want to go another form for updation.

This updation button together with the texboxes must appear when a GRID VIEW row is clicked.Appreciate ur help

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
End If
```

In this onclick i want the row to be expanded.

Comment: my issue is not for updating the database but when clicking the row (with 4 fields),i want that row to be expanded down with 14 fields.

Comment: Well, you will have to explain a bit more what you want, what have you tried, and what didn't work. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: OK, I will remove my Downvote for the effort. I have tagged ASP.NET (it is the first question that I should have ask you...) correct it if it's wrong. And hope somebody understand...

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly; you should try using a Repeater control (which allows customization on each of the item) instead of a GridView which only renders rows and cols in a tabular form. In the Repeater control, for each item template you can have a panel, having those set of controls, for which you can set the Visible property true (either through javascript or server code).